# The exported data directory is empty

Tags: database, cnosdb

I used cnosdb image to pull up a container, wrote some data in the database, then connected to the database on the host and exported the data. I found that the host data directory was empty, but the export showed that it was successful. What's going on? ? Why is my exported data missing?

What's going on? ? Why is my exported data missing?